# how can we update a collection by using mongodb mapreduce?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm doing **perform incremental mapreduce**. My dataset is network logs for each day we are getting one log. So, each log data we are creating one collection. In database we are having different collections for different days. Doing mapreduce on first day collection and stored output in **someone** collection. The dataset input for mapreduce is

### intput

```
{
    "_id": "1.1.145.219_1341627848904",
    "client_ip": "1.1.145.219",
    "timestamp": "1341627848904",
    "bytes_transfered": 0
}

{
    "_id": "1.1.145.219_1341627848926",
    "client_ip": "1.1.145.219",
    "timestamp": "1341627848926",
    "bytes_transfered": 3
}

{
    "_id": "1.1.145.219_1341627849227",
    "client_ip": "1.1.145.219",
    "timestamp": "1341627849227",
    "bytes_transfered": 5
}

{
    "_id": "1.1.145.219_1341627849250",
    "client_ip": "1.1.145.219",
    "timestamp": "1341627849250",
    "bytes_transfered": 8
}

{
    "_id": "1.1.145.219_1341627849277",
    "client_ip": "2.3.45.89",
    "timestamp": "1341627849277",
    "bytes_transfered": 11
}

{
    "_id": "1.1.145.219_1341627849298",
    "client_ip": "2.3.45.89",
    "timestamp": "1341627849298",
    "bytes_transfered": 14
}

{
    "_id": "1.1.145.219_1341627849529",
    "client_ip": "2.3.45.89",
    "timestamp": "1341627849529",
    "bytes_transfered": 17
}
```

Based on "client_ip", we are adding "bytes_transfered" for every client_ip. We are getting output after mapreduce is

### output:

```
{"_id":"1.1.145.219", "value":16}

{"_id":"2.3.45.89", "value":42}
```

we are running mapreduce on second day collection the output stored to same collection. Now my question is if any "client_ip" is exist in someone collection, I want update and add value to the "bytes_transfered" filed based on "client_ip". If no "client_ip" exists it will create new document on same collection.

### MyCode

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');

var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost:27017/upload', ['twotimes', 'data']);

var mapper = function() {

    emit(this.client_ip, this.bytes_transfered)

};

var reduce = function(key, values) {

    var val = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {

    val += values[i];

    };

    return val;

};

db.twotimes.mapReduce(

    mapper,

    reduce,

    {

    query: {
        "timestamp": {
            $gt: "1341599400000",
            $lt: "1341682200000"
        }
    },

    out: 'data'

    }

);
```

Please suggest me, How can I resolve this issue.

Regards,

Naresh Balija.

Comment: Side question: why don't you use a compound `_id: { ip:..., timestamp: new ISODate()})`?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: I tried as you said "client_ip and timestamp" as compound key. Here "timestamp" are unique for each document, so we can't aggregate "bytes_transfered". It is not possible.